# Regular expression checking URLs, only allowing lowercase

Tags: regex, google-forms

I am trying to create a regular expression for a Google Forms field. The goal is to only allow users to enter a URL in a very specific format:

- No "http://" or "www." in front
- No trailing slashes
- Only lowercase characters

Examples

- http://example.com - FALSE
- example.com/ - FALSE
- Example.com - FALSE
- example.com - TRUE

What I achieved so far is the first two criteria, but how can I force only lower case characters?

```
([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your regex **already** allows only lower case characters. (As long as you don't set the `I`gnore case flag.)

Comment: The `[\da-z.-]+\.[a-z.]{2,6}` with *Regular Expression* -> *Matches* mode works for me.

Comment: Sorry! Have to admit that it works in Google Forms. However, I want to use the same for data validation in a Google Sheets cell. There, the formula         `=REGEXMATCH(A1, "([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})")` does return TRUE for Uppercase characters instead of FALSE

Comment: I guess you need `^[\da-z.-]+\.[a-z.]{2,6}$`.

Comment: Awesome, that's it! Thank you for the very fast help!